# producer connect to consumer with unix domain sockets

Tags: tcp, socket, node.js

I have this:

```
producer-client | consumer-server
```

the consumer starts a tcp server listening on a unix domain socket (something like that), and the client (the producer) will connect to it.

However, there's a race condition obviously - right now I just have a timeout of about 500ms to wait for the consumer to boot up and start listening for connections. My question is - is there some event I can listen to? I suppose I could poll and test for a connection, after a timeout. Is there some synchronous utility I can use to poll to see if something is listening on that unix domain socket?

#### UPDATE #1

So in the consumer, I delete/unlink the file, and then start listening on it In the producer, I create the file if it doesn't exist, and then use `inotify` to listen for changes to it, upon a change, then I know the server in the consumer is now listening.

Comment: a tcp server listening on a unix domain socket (something like that) ？Really hard to read, A process listening on a SOCK_STREAM unix domain socket?

Comment: Yeah idk for sure, I just know I use the 'net' package with Node.js and it can use TCP on a port/host or unix domain sockets, so I guess UDS is completely different than TCP?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. You already said you're listening on connection. If you want to check all the states of unix domain socket on your system, use `netstat`,

Answer (score 2):

If the `producer-client` and the `consumer-server` are not talking across the pipe but via a socket, you should not be running them in a pipeline.

So instead,

```sh
consumer-server &
sleep 2
producer-client &

wait
```

This would start up the server as a background job, wait for two seconds to let the server initialise everything, and then start the client as a background job as well.  The script then waits for both to terminate.

As you yourself suggest, the client may also just wait for the appearance of the socket file, here not using `inotify`:

```sh
consumer-server &

while [ ! -S /path/to/socket ]; do
    echo Waiting for socket to appear... >&2
    sleep 1
done
producer-client &

wait
```

The `while` loop (or an equivalent *thing*) could also be part of what the `producer-client` is doing internally.

---

If the server and the client are not talking across the pipe, then your pipeline

```sh
producer-client | consumer-server
```

is essentially the same as

```sh
producer-client &
consumer-server
```

My suggested set of commands (above) modifies this to insert a short delay between the the invocation of the two, and also runs the client as a background task (which is not strictly necessary).